# How to assign click event to nav tag?

Tags: jquery

I tried to display alert message with text of clicked menu item but it does not want to work, how I should do that ?

```js
$("#navigation").on("click", function () {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
   <nav id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

- Home
- Services
- Portfolio
- About
- Blog
- Contact

Comment: $("#navigation") ?

Comment: As @itsgoingdown mentioned you just need to add `#` on your selector for `id`.

Comment: @itsgoingdown still does not work

Comment: You didn't add jQuery to your snippet.Works fine when you do https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0jrrj0do/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get text of clicked item with `text()`

```js
$('#navigation li a').click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the selector properly,

```
$("#navigation ul.nav > li > a").on("click", function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

And use `.text()` to extract the clicked element's text content.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c8h0mp50/)